# Minify HTML after template compilation with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, frontend, ejs

I am using webpack for building static HTML pages with ejs as a template lang.

But at the output I get a not minified HTML page.

My building script is:

```
"debug": "webpack -d --progress --color",
"release": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p --progress --color"
```

My webpack.config is here:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "raw!html-minify"
        },
        {
            test: /\.ejs$/,
            loader: "ejs-compiled"
        },
      ...
    ]
},
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: "underscore"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Custom template',
        template: './src/views/index.ejs'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
    })
],
...
```

Template look like this

```
<% include el/header.ejs %>
```

What should I do to minify HTML after ejs compiled it?